# contenteditable plaintext-only mobile not working

Tags: html

I have contenteditable plaintext-only table cell like:

```
<td contenteditable="plaintext-only">input</td>
```

it works perfectly on chrome and other browser, when I test it on mobile, when new line it inserts

```
<br>
```

It can enter input but looks like the plaintext-only mode is not working, both the same for Chrome and Safari.

I would like to know what is the issue here for mobile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!